# Sending json data to client from an interface server without change

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, servicestack-text

I have two type of servers which contain some information.
One of them is **Interface Server** that is used for collecting all information in one place and pass it to mobile devices.
I used `httpClient` to get JSON data with REST from data servers.
I want to pass this json data directly to  the mobile devices without any deserialization or serialization in my **Interface Server**.

String is a good solution but it deserializes this result from json:

`"\"{\\\"Count\\\":5}\""`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in that case, string is _not_ a good solution, is it? Have you tried NewtonSoft.JSON? You can keep everything in object form and pass it around your app. Then send it on to the client unchanged. The library will take care of serialising, and should pass on an identical object.

Comment: @ADyson can you explain how can I do this?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm and http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm will start you off. Although if you're using MVC to return data to the client, you can just use the JSONResult class and return your object directly, it uses NewtonSoft underneath anyway. You can easily google how to return JSON from MVC.